# Text Classification using Pre-trained Word vectors without a neural network

Tags: python, text, classification, embedding

Background: I have been evaluating a variety of text classification methods on my dataset, including using feature vectors derived from word counts and TF-IDF, and then running these through various classifiers. My dataset is very small (about 2300 sentences and about 5 classes), and considering the above approaches treat different ones as completely separate, would like to use a word vector approach to classification. I have used pretrained word vectors with a shallow NN with little success.

Problem: I am looking for an alternative method of using word vectors to classify my sentences and have thought of taking the word vectors for a sentence, combining them into a single vector, then taking the centroid of each class of sentence vectors - classification would then happen via a distance measure between a new sentence and the centroid.

How can I combine the word vectors into a "sentence vector" given my small dataset?

Comment: Have you looked into word2vec and doc2vec?

Answer (score 1):

A great feature of word2vecs is that you can perform simple operations on them. One common way of getting from words to sentences, is to simply take the average your word vectors for all words in your sentence.

since your sample data is small, I'd use a pertained embedding from [Gensim Data](https://github.com/RaRe-Technologies/gensim-data), retrain using your own sample, and at the end use a simpler classifier like logistic regression.

To Nathan's point if you want to classify documents, Doc2Vec is a great extension of Word2Vec which reduces a lot of the steps. With a few iterations, you can actually achieve really good results. [Here](https://towardsdatascience.com/multi-class-text-classification-with-doc2vec-logistic-regression-9da9947b43f4) is a great implementation of Doc2Vec.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you need to know where to split your sentences first, then you can use a doc2vec model for those sentences.

https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html

1. Determine where your sentence boundaries are
2. Model sentence splitting
3. Train Doc2Vec model on sentences
4. Input sentence vectors to NN model

Ive done this with limited success. Your corpus is small but you can always try it out and then test/validate/evaluate!

Good luck

Answer (score 0):

I would use gensim's implementation of Paragraph Vector, [Doc2Vec](https://radimrehurek.com/gensim/models/doc2vec.html) for this. I've just written [an article](https://jackdry.com/using-doc2vec-to-classify-movie-reviews) describing how to use it classify movie reviews, which might help you!